# How to prevent including the same page in nested pages classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

I have to include a page to every page except itself. This page is for XSRF protection. However, some of these pages are also included in other pages, as a result, redefinition of functions and variables.

Is there a way to check this so that for every rendered page, only one is included? It must be included in every page so that if an attacker uses the URL directly, it won't be vulnerable to that attack.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps?

[This class allows you to dynamic include a file into your script.](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7651&lngWId=4)

alternativley have a look here:
[Implementing lazy-loaded modules in VBScript (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497851/implementing-lazy-loaded-modules-in-vbscript)